# Proving a given function equals o(N)

Tags: algorithm, little-o

I am trying to prove that for any constant,`k`, `log^k N = o(N)` (little O of N)

All that I know for little o is that it follows the form `T(n) = o(p(n))` where `T(n)` grows at a rate slower than `p(n)`. Also I can't really do a limit and use `L'hopital rule` because I do not know what `f(n)` or `g(n)` is. Can someone please help getting me started!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show that

```
    lim        (log^k N)/N  = 0
N -> infinity
```

Write `N = e^x`, and that becomes

```
lim (x^k)/(e^x) = 0
```

Now, use the Power series expansion of the exponential function,

```
e^x = ∑ (x^n)/n!
```

to get an estimate for that quotient.

> Spoiler: Picking the term with `n = k+1` gives `e^x > x^(k+1)/(k+1)!` and from that easily follows `(x^k)/(e^x) < (k+1)!/x`.

Comment: Am I looking for a value or just a general statement

Comment: You're looking for a general statement, aren't you? You want to prove "For all k, log^k N \in o(N)", that is a general statement, and as such its proof needs to be general.